# Equivalent awk syntax for a[x][0]+=$2

Tags: awk, gawk

What is the proper awk syntax for this following piece of code, which I think is for gawk: `a[x][0]+=$2`

Comment: What is that code doing? What context is it operating in?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On one level - there is no equivalent, that's why the gawk code to support it was written.

Whether or not you actually need all the functionality that comes with that syntax depends what you're going to do with the array afterwards and if you're not doing much with it then the implementation you need might be as simple as:

```
a[x,0]+=$2
```

but it might also be something like:

```
a[x,0]+=$2; b[x]=(x in b?b[x] SUBSEP:"") 0
```

and if you need to do the equivalent of:

```
split("1 3 5 7",a[x]); ... ; a[x][0]+=$2
```

then you have some head scratching to do.

Comment: the code is used in an answer provided to one of my other questions found here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29525839/sorting-uniq-strings-creatings-columns-and-averaging

The first suggestion a[x,0]+=$2 seems to solve the syntax error problem.

Comment: That answer is doing additional gawk-specific things like using `l=length(a[x])` to get the length of an array and it's doing some things that are just not very awk-ish (parens on the prints, using string concatenation to create format strings, testing for an array having zero value instead of absent indices, etc.) so it makes me wonder if the poster really came up with the best awk solution. You shouldn't have accepted it and closed the question if it doesn't do what you want as others might have looked at it and provided other answers.